# Google Earth freezes during zoom-in on Intel processors with integrated graphics

Tags: 12.04, kernel, graphics, intel-graphics, google-earth

When I zoom in at a certain zoom level, Google Earth makes my system freeze completely so that I have to power off or reboot

I use Kubuntu 12.04 and my laptop has an Intel(R)Core(TM)i3-2310M CPU @2.10GHz with HD3000 graphics.

I installed `intel-gpu-tools` and tried to fix it with `sudo intel_reg_write 0x2120 0x1206800` as explained [here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/earth/vUGP9-6UucM), but that didn't work.

I wonder if there any other solution out there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The best option is to patch the Intel Graphics driver for your current kernel

This occurs in OpenGL applications because of [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/975689) in the kernel's `i915` Intel GPU driver.

The best option is to patch the `i915` module for your existing kernel using the solution in [comment #12](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/975689/comments/12) of that bug report.

It will take a little time and effort...

#### Here's how...

1. Open a terminal with `Ctrl-Alt-T` (or open *Konsole* for Kubuntu)
2. Type or paste `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get distupgrade -y`, press enter, type your password and let it finish.
3. Then type/paste these, one after the other:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential patch
   mkdir ksrc
   cd ksrc
   apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
   cd linux-3.2.0
   wget -O- https://launchpadlibrarian.net/103494967/fix-intel-gpu-crash-3.2.diff | patch -p1
   make oldconfig
   make drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915.ko
   DIR915=/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/i915
   sudo mv $DIR915/i915.ko $DIR915/i915_old.ko
   sudo cp drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915.ko $DIR915/i915.ko
   ```
4. Reboot, and hopefully your Google Earth problem should be fixed. In that case, you can remove the linux source by going into the terminal and typing `rm -rf ksrc`. If there are any graphics problems, you can revert to the old driver with:

   ```
   DIR915=/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/i915
   sudo cp $DIR915/i915_old.ko $DIR915/i915.ko
   ```
5. You will have to re-do this procedure whenever a new 3.2 kernel is released, which thankfully isn't often! There is also the chance that the patch will be included (backported) in one of these upgrades.

Comment: I've followed your instruction till Step #3 and then reboot. On my first attempt to run Google Earth, it did freeze for one moment and then the Google Earth just disappear. But my system did not freeze. I restarted the system and made second attempt. This time, Google Earth did freeze completely along with my system. I had to have it power off. I haven't remove the linux source but tend to revert to the old driver as explained in Step #4. But, it didn't work and said cp: cannot stat ... No such file or directory. Do I need to repeat un-install and re-install Google Earth?

Comment: Sorry, in Step 4 it is an underscore **_** in **i915_old**, I edited it. I have an i7-2620 (also HD Graphics 3000), I'll try to see why the patch doesn't fix this.

Comment: Thank you mate. Do I need to un-install and re-install Google Earth? I intended to but couldn't find the _uninstall command_ in terminal cause _sudo apt-get remove google-earth*.*_ didn't work.

Comment: You can uninstall with `sudo dpkg --remove google-earth-stable`

Comment: Hello mate, I repeat Step #3 from the _make oldconfig_ command to _sudo cp drivers_ command.  Then, I did un-install and re-install Google Earth.  Restart the machine and run Google Earth. It does works flawlessly! Thank you very much mate, you're a hero.